# How to get data for a common layout file and to display on all views

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a common layout file which use to extend the common features such as navbar footer. So now I need to get data from my database 
eg: number of users in navbar
and to display them in all views.
So my common layout file has no controllers or routes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppServiceProvider's boot function to pass variable to specific view or multiple views with view Composer. Try using following example.

```
public function boot()
{
    \View::composer('url_here', function ($view) {
        $view->with('$post', \App\Post::all());
    });
}
```

[here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) is the official documentation.